# Why won't this variable load?

Tags: java, variables

***The Short Story***

I've created a program, below. I want to import a package I created into the program. I can't figure out why compiler doesn't recognize my address variable, whose class is located in a file under the package I created

address, name and date all share the same syntax, but the compiler doesn't recognize address. After removing address and executing the program with the remaining classes, I can successfully run my program. I can't do so with address, however.

---

***Further Details***

I created a program that prompts a user to enter the number of employees he or she wants to create, through the command line. A user then enters information about an employee's name, adddress and hire date and the program displays this information.

The code below DOES NOT CONTAIN classes for name, address and date, although I've referenced objects (and then fields) within those mentioned classes. Those classes have been saved in other files under one folder, because I'm trying to run my code as a package.

The folder's name is util -- hence the package name is util. Each source code begins with
`package util;`

---

```
import util.*;

public class EmployeeA
{
    Name name;
    Date date;
    Address address;

    public EmployeeA()
    {
        name = new Name();
        date = new Date();
        address = new Address();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        EmployeeA[] array = new EmployeeA[x];

        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new EmployeeA();
            array[i].name.name = Input.getString("Enter employee first name and last name");
            array[i].date.date = Input.getString("Enter employee hire date in MM/DD/YYYY");
            array[i].address.address = Input.getString("Enter employee address");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i].name.name + " was hired on " + array[i].date.date + " and lives on "
                    + array[i].address.address);

    }
}



                    }
```

source file #1

```
package util; 

public class Address
{
   String address;
}
```

source file #2

```
package util;
public class Date
{
    String date ;
}
```

source file #3

```
package util;

public class Name
{
    String name ;
}
```

employeeA.java:27: error: cannot find symbol

```
array [i].address.address = Input.getString("Enter employee address");
                 ^
```

symbol:   variable address
 location: variable address of type Address

employeeA.java:31: error: cannot find symbol

```
System.out.println (array[i].name.name + " was hired on " + array[i].date.date + " and lives on " +  array[i].address.address);
                                                                                                                     ^
```

symbol:   variable address
 location: variable address of type Address

Comment: And the error you see is what?  What command are you using to compile the code?

Comment: This code is very hard to read with inconsistent indentations.

Comment: you should fix the alignment

Comment: haha let me learn the proper conventions for allignment, but will do so. i just posted the error on the post

Comment: press ctrl+shift+O in Eclipse it will import the proper classes

Comment: what is `Input.getString(String);` ?

Comment: if the clsses are in different packages, set their variables (eg name) as public.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why aren't you using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA CE? They're both free.

Comment: started using it yesterday. before that, had been using text edit + terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `address` field within `Address` has no access modifiers - therefore it is only available to classes in the same package. Your `EmployeeA` class is not in the same package (it has no `package` statement), therefore it can't see it. You *could* make it public - but it would be better to make it *private* and add a method to access it (`getAddress()`). See the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details.

Having said that, your existing types are pretty anaemic at the moment - and certainly there are better types for representing a date than `String`...

Comment: Implicit `Package` visibility. Nice catch.

Comment: The OP said that every class was in the `util` package.  Looking carefully at his code, `employeeA` is not.  Nice catch.

Comment: sorry there -- employeeA would also have to declare `package util;` ? I thought that, since employeeA is importing the package, there'd be no need

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Just for my understanding: why didn't package-private also hide name and date?

Comment: @user21945: No, because it's still not *in* the same package... and that's what package access requires. And as for `name` and `date` - it *should* fail on those too, given the code you've shown us. (They fail for me - I've just tried...)

Comment: do I understand now?      if I declare `package util;` before my EmployeeA class, my classes are now visible to each other. Alternatively, I could keep EmployeeA under the default package but change address,date and name to public. Changing those fields to public would allow EmployeeA class to use them?

Comment: @user21945: Um, I don't know - nothing you've done can tell me whether or not you understand the problem...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet. sorry there -- added a comment before I finished typing

Comment: @user21945: Yes - although the *classes* are already visible because they're public. It's the *fields* which aren't. But it's generally a bad idea for one class to use the fields in another class anyway - it's better to express that via getters and setters. Separate out "what you can do with a class" (its API) from "how the class achieves that" (its implementation). In most cases, I regard fields as part of the implementation, so they should be private.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have an extra close curly bracket at the end of the EmployeeA class. Directly below the plus sign on the last line. I suspect that is causing it not to compile properly.